# Unsure how the ancestry gem for rails works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ancestry

I am trying to use the [ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) which I found by watching an old [Ryan Bates Ancestry video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry) and so I set up my my stuff like so:

**Migration:**

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :comment
      t.string :author
      t.integer :post_id
      t.string :ancestry
      t.index  :ancestry
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Model:**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  has_ancestry

  validates :comment, presence: true, length: {minimum: 15}
  validates :author, presence: true
end
```

** Controller new Action: **

```
  def new
    post = Post.find_by(id: params[:post_id])
    post.comments.new(:ancenstry => params[:parent_id])
  end
```

So I think I have set up everything correctly. But when I run the following test:

```
it "should create a nested comment for a post" do
  posted_comment = FactoryGirl.create(:comment, post_id: @post.id)
  post :create, :post_id => @post.id, comment: {author: @comment.author, comment: @comment.comment, parent_id: @comment.id}
  json = JSON.parse(response.body).to_json
  binding.pry
  parse_json(json, 'comment').to_json.should have_json_path('id')
end
```

And inspect the json after the binding pry:

```
{
   "comment":{
      "id":9,
      "post_id":6,
      "author":"Adam",
      "comment":"Some Really long Valid Comment length of Something.",
      "ancestry":null
   }
}
```

The ancestry section is null. I have even tried tried changing `parent_id` to `ancestry` but that doesn't help either. Does any know what I am doing wrong? or have any ideas?

Comment: You spelled `ancestry` incorrectly in your `new` action. Is this a typo on SO-only, or could this be causing your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`post.comments.new(:ancenstry => params[:parent_id])`

The key of your hash is misspelled.